# CSS and HTML files not loading in IDE

Tags: windows, java-ee-8

My Java EE app is returning a 404 status when trying to load CSS and HTML files. Any ideas? Problem is happening with any browser, internal or external. The problem did not exist prior to editing a couple of JS files. In the process of troubleshooting JS files executions, I deleted and re-added my server and the problem has persisted ever since. All JS files are loading. The problem persists with deployment to the live website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```